# OS-independent LLVM IR system calls

Tags: llvm, system-calls

1) Is it possible, using IRBuilder, to generate system calls independent of operation system? I have read this: http://llvm.lyngvig.org/Articles/Mapping-High-Level-Constructs-to-LLVM-IR#59
It seems like that when I generate LLVM IR and want to generate system call for e.g output to terminal, then I must tailor the LLVM IR to Linux/Windows/Mac. Or does LLVM have some interface for system calls?

2) Has this tool http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html ability to do the stuff I want in 1) ?

Comment: I would also appreciate any tip for study material about linking, system calls and this stuff.

Comment: there's an answer here, but it's not platform independent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053553/syscall-sysenter-on-llvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not. LLVM is a compiler backend; it does not concern itself with system calls. System calls are usually employed inside the platform's C library, which implements them with a mixture of low-level C and target-specific assembly. System calls are both OS and target (CPU) dependent.

As for more materials on studying this stuff - you have my sympathy. It's not a well documented area, because 99.9% of programmers never need to operate at this level. I suggest you start picking up some basic assembly programming and go from there.

Comment: Thank you! So what is the solution when I want to write LLVM IR for my toy language which should print "Hello world" both on Linux and Windows terminal?

Comment: @OndrejSmid: you can invoke a standard C library function like `puts` and link the object file created from your IR with the C library. If you want to avoid the C library you'll have to implement your own wrappers for syscalls

Comment: LLVM is not a compiler backend per se, it's the infrastructure that any compiler backend might be accounted as a part of it.