# if i want to create a language with llvmlite, how to implement a socket?

Tags: python, sockets, llvm, llvmlite

I already know how to write Lexer and Parser。
If I want this programming language to communicate, how can I implement socket？

Comment: You have to emit calls to system socket functions (`socket`, `connect`, `send`, `recv`, etc.)

Comment: how to add system call for the language?

Comment: You generate a [syscall or sysenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27714659/fnord) instruction with [the right arguments for that particular kernel-side function](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/#fast-system-calls).

Comment: It's very useful to me. Thank you.